# Attribute to skip over statement in unit test c#

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I am looking to skip a certain statement in my unit tests eg:

```
if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to remove " + contact.CompanyName + " from the contacts?", "Confirm Delete", MessageBoxButton.YesNo, MessageBoxImage.Question, MessageBoxResult.Yes) == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
```

is there an attribute i can place above the statement to avoid the unit test executing it?

Comment: What unit testing framework are you using?

Comment: Are you using NUnit framework?

Comment: I just create a new test project from visual studio 2010, not sure the framework

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should try to avoid directly calling GUI components in the classes you are unit testing. One way around this would be to create an interface, say IMessageBoxDisplayService, which can be stubbed out for the test

```
public MyClass(IMessageBoxDisplayService messageBoxDisplayService)
{ 
    ...
    if (messageBoxDisplayService.Show(message)) ...
```

Comment: Ok sounds like the best way forward, but is there an attribute that will skip over a statement in the interface- regardless of the statement?

Comment: You can use the Conditional attribute to skip over a method.

Answer (score 3):

You can also try using [Moles](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/pex/) to stub out the call to MessageBox.Show().

Answer (score 0):

You're probably thinking of the [Conditional()] attribute:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664622%28VS.71%29.aspx

I think you're better off with an Mark's interface solution though.